# PHP multidimensional arrays (Importing Twitter Results)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array result that contains multiple arrays. I need to grab all of the "text" fields of the 2nd level of arrays and combine them into a single variable. I'm drawing a blank on how to do this

Array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [created_at] => Mon, 20 Aug 2012 18:31:50 +0000 
    [from_user] => CollectHW 
    [from_user_id] => 769712384 
    [from_user_id_str] => 769712384 
    [from_user_name] => Collect Hot Wheels 
    [geo] => 
    [id] => 237617956643827712 
    [id_str] => 237617956643827712 
    [iso_language_code] => en 
    [metadata] => stdClass Object ( 
        [result_type] => recent ) 
    [profile_image_url] => url 
    [profile_image_url_https] => url
    [source] => web **
    [text] => Second Tweet #step2** 
    [to_user] => 
    [to_user_id] => 0 
    [to_user_id_str] => 0 
    [to_user_name] => ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
    [created_at] => Mon, 20 Aug 2012 16:41:53 +0000 
    [from_user] => CollectHW 
    [from_user_id] => 769712384 
    [from_user_id_str] => 769712384 
    [from_user_name] => Collect Hot Wheels 
    [geo] => 
    [id] => 237590287504011264 
    [id_str] => 237590287504011264 
    [iso_language_code] => en 
    [metadata] => stdClass Object ( 
        [result_type] => recent ) 
    [profile_image_url] => url 
    [profile_image_url_https] => url 
    [source] => web **
    [text] => First Tweet #step1** 
    [to_user] => 
    [to_user_id] => 0 
    [to_user_id_str] => 0 
    [to_user_name] => ) 
)
```

Comment: Can you make this human-readable? Use `<pre>` tags around your array dump FYI.

Comment: Welcome to SO, [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @Matt I formatted it for you buddy.

Comment: @njk thanks, that hurt my eyes to look at.

Comment: @Matt I have been a PHP developer for 4 years and never thought of using <pre> to make print_r readable. *facepalm* and +1 for that tip.

Comment: @Erty every day I go on SO I learn great "new" techniques to make my job easier.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting this was my first post on these forums. @njk I appreciate the extra help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    echo "The text for $i is: " . $array[$i][text] . "\n";
}
```

**Result**

```
The text for 0 is: Second Tweet #step2**
The text for 1 is: First Tweet #step1**
```

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I need. I will test it hopefully this afternoon!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$text = '';

foreach($array as $item) {
    $text .= $item['text'];
}
```

EDIT: since the array contains stdClass instances, you may instead need to do:

```
$text = '';

foreach($array as $item) {
    $text .= $item->text;
}
```

Pretty much the same thing.  I'm not sure if PHP objects can have their properties accessed with array notation.  So, try the first one, and if it doesn't work, do the second.